# How do I easily restore purchases using the Amazon API?

Tags: amazon-in-app-purchase

I'm trying to restore purchases just like iOS, and I can't figure out how to easily restore an IAP entitlement purchase with the Amazon API.

If I send another request with the SKU to the `PurchasingManager`, it returns a `PurchaseResponse`, but that `PurchaseResponse` doesn't return a valid Receipt if the SKU has already been purchased. It's null.

Seems like I would need that SKU to do any kind of processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found how to do this.

Turns out a different function call is needed instead of the `initiatePurchaseRequest` call.

```
PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequest(Offset offset)
```

This call gets all the purchases the user has made then returns them to the PurchasingObserver to be handled by:

```
PurchasingObserver.onPurchaseUpdatesResponse(PurchaseUpdatesResponse purchaseUpdatesResponse)
```