# How to restore purchases in Amazon API?

Tags: android, amazon-in-app-purchase

I have been trying from past few days to restore the purchased items in In-App Purchases in Amazon. I succeeded in purchasing items, and now I need to restore the items purchased after the app is uninstalled. I read the several links and including the following one as well:

[Tracking In-App Purchases Using PurchaseUpdates](https://developer.amazon.com/post/Tx1ZQ21OBPY53N0/Tracking-In-App-Purchases-Using-PurchaseUpdates.html)

This link has got some good information, and after reading the following link:

[How do I easily restore purchases using the Amazon API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078428/how-do-i-easily-restore-purchases-using-the-amazon-api)

I know that I need to use onPurchaseUpdatesResponse() to get things done here, but the problem is that I am getting

```
    Set<Receipt> receipts = response.getReceipts();
    Set<String> revokedSkus = response.getRevokedSkus();
```

both empty in onPurchaseUpdatesResponse() method. I can see the purchased items in AmazonSDKTester app, and the userId obtained by:

```
    response.getUserId();
```

is same as in AmazonSDKTester app.

I think I might be doing something wrong in storing the offset after my purchases done successfully. But, I am not able to understand how to do things right here or what am I doing wrong, Thanks for listening and please help!

I am setting offset as:

```
        Offset offset = purchaseDataStorage.getPurchaseUpdatesOffset();
        PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequest(offset);
```

and I am doing this in onGetUserIdResponse() method when the case is SUCCESSFUL.

And I am storing the offset value in onPurchaseUpdatesResponse() when the case is SUCCESSFUL:

```
Offset offset = response.getOffset();
purchaseDataStorage.savePurchaseUpdatesOffset(offset);
```

Comment: Are you using PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequest(Offset.BEGINNING)?  Note the parameter value.

Comment: @DrC Please read the Edited version of my question and thanks for the quick response, really thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first call or when doing a user initiated restore, you want to use the Offset.BEGINNING key value to initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequest to get all transactions not just ones that have occurred since the last query.

Comment: Thanks for the response, now I am getting receipts non empty and the revoked skus as empty. Two more questions here 1) when are revoked skus called. 2) what is the best place to call PurchasingManager.initiatePurchaseUpdatesRequest(Offset.BEGINNING);

Comment: I call it in response to a user request (button) and in onGetUSerIdResponse when I have no offset recorded for the user (basically, first run).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really helped solving my problem. Have a great New Year. Happy New Year!!!